# Relation between two collection mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have 2 collection in my mongodb base: Category and Book

the category.js

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var categoryModel = new Schema({
  catName: String,
  menuKey: String
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('Category', categoryModel);
```

and the book.js

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var bookModel = new Schema({
  title: String,
  author: String,
  category: String ,
  summary: String ,
  cover: String ,
  price: Number,
  qte: Number,
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('book', bookModel);
```

It is possible to add:

> var category = require ('./category.js')

and repalce this line  :

> category: String ,

by

> category: [category],

Answer (score 4, accepted):

here is the solution which satisfy your requirement.

```
//category.js
    var mongoose = require("mongoose");
    var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
    var categoryModel = new Schema({
      catName: String,
      menuKey: String
    });
    module.exports = mongoose.model('Category', categoryModel);

    //book.js
    var mongoose = require("mongoose");
    var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
    var bookModel = new Schema({
      title: String,
      author: String,
      category: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Category' }],
      summary: String ,
      cover: String ,
      price: Number,
      qte: Number,
    });
    module.exports = mongoose.model('book', bookModel);
```

Answer (score 2):

`category: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Category'}`

Answer (score 2):

You do not want to do that. You want to indicate the relationship using the `ref` keyword, using which you reference a `Schema.ObjectId` in another collection.

From the [official populate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) documentation for mongoose:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
  , Schema = mongoose.Schema

var personSchema = Schema({
  _id     : Number,
  name    : String,
  age     : Number,
  stories : [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Story' }]
});

var storySchema = Schema({
  _creator : { type: Number, ref: 'Person' },
  title    : String,
  fans     : [{ type: Number, ref: 'Person' }]
});

var Story  = mongoose.model('Story', storySchema);
var Person = mongoose.model('Person', personSchema);
```

---

In your case you'd have a `Book` model referencing the `Category`.